# Handling CKErrors while using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer, ckerror

I have an app that uses Core Data, works great. I decided to try to use iCloud to sync data across multiple devices. I followed the basic steps of changing NSPersistentContainer to NSPersistenCloudKitContainer and adding iCloud capabilities, enabling CloudKit and Background Modes (remote notifications). With those few changes, data is syncing between devices as it should. Seemed very simple.

But, if the users iCloud storage gets full, the app continues to function and persist locally but sync stops (obviously) without notifying the user.

I understand it's a quotaExceeded error, but how would I go about accessing that error then handling it (and handling CKErrors in general)?

I feel like this NSPersistentCloudKitContainer is a wall that I can't get through to be able to handle CKErrors. I'm a beginner so maybe I'm missing something obvious but can't find any answers online.

Sticking with the quotaExceeded error situation:

- Step 1 - CKError.Code.quotaExceeded occurs.
- Step 2 - ???
- Step 3 - Notify user that their iCloud storage is full.

What does step 2 look like?

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 - Monitor NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.Event for event types and changes.

A solution was found in ggruen's answer (in their Misc section) in this question:
[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer: How to check if data is synced to CloudKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138880/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-how-to-check-if-data-is-synced-to-cloudkit)

From there I was able to handle CKErrors using the sample code in that answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Crew3339 have your been able to fix this? I posted a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384869/cloudkit-how-to-handle-ckerror-partialfailure-when-using-nspersistentcloudkitco because I want to inform the user about a CKError.Code.quotaExceeded but I can't access the details of the error. Thanks.

Comment: @alpennec, I checked out your question and my situation is identical. CKErrors can be handled from here, but partialErrorsByItemID and errorUserInfo is returning no data. After contacting Apple Developer Technical Support, they determined the empty returns to be a Core Data bug.