# Detecting Quota exceeded in iCloud storage

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data, cloudkit

I am trying to detect when a user's iCloud storage is full so I can put a special message up in my app.  I have filled up my iCloud storage so that when I run my app I get the following error:

> error: CoreData+CloudKit: -NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _requestAbortedNotInitialized:: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x281ddc1e0> - Never successfully initialized and cannot execute request '<NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x2841e00f0> 51383346-87BA-44D8-B527-A0B1EE35A0EF' due to error: <CKError 0x282c50db0: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; uuid = 7BA17495-4F05-4AF4-A463-C0DF5A823B2E; container ID = "iCloud.com.neufsters.pangram"; partial errors: {
> E30B2972-FD4B-4D2A-BD1C-EB6F33F5367D:(com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:_*defaultOwner*_) = <CKError 0x282c155f0: "Quota Exceeded" (25/2035); server message = "Quota exceeded"; op = FC4D3188D0A46ABC; uuid = 7BA17495-4F05-4AF4-A463-C0DF5A823B2E; Retry after 315.0 seconds>
> 2FC9A487-D630-444D-B7F4-27A0F3A6B46E:(com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:_*defaultOwner*_) = <CKError 0x282c52820: "Quota Exceeded" (25/2035); server message = "Quota exceeded"; op = FC4D3188D0A46ABC; uuid = 7BA17495-4F05-4AF4-A463-C0DF5A823B2E; Retry after 315.0 seconds>
> 903DD6A0-0BD8-46C0-84FB-E89797514D9F:(com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:_*defaultOwner*_) = <CKError 0x282c513e0: "Quota Exceeded" (25/\2035); server message = "Quota exceeded"; op = FC4D3188D0A46ABC; uuid = 7BA17495-4F05-4AF4-A463-C0DF5A823B2E; Retry after 315.0 seconds>. }>

I have tried using code similar to [NSPersistentCloudKitContainer: How to check if data is synced to CloudKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138880/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-how-to-check-if-data-is-synced-to-cloudkit) to get callbacks when there are CloudKit events, but I never get a .quotaExceeded error code, and partialErrorsByItemID is always empty.

Any suggestions on how I can detect iCloud quota exceeded?

Comment: It'd help if you added the code you are using as well as the error.

Comment: I don't have code which causes this.  When the app starts up there are some background CloudKit processes which sync to iCloud and they are what produce this log message.  I'm hoping there's a way to hook into some notification system which could get a callback when the .quotaExceeded error occurs.