# Duplicated records with the same `objectId` in Core Data with CloudKit

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Swift App that uses Core Data with CloudKit. CloudKit duplicated all records in the container, across all of my devices. The duplicated records have the same `objectId`. My code uses NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy so I assumed CloudKit would have merged the records on Apple's servers. What could have caused this? How can it be prevented?

Below is how I create the container.

Thank you

```
class DataManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var containerImpl: NSPersistentContainer? = nil
    
    var container: NSPersistentContainer {
        if containerImpl == nil {
            containerImpl = makeLazyContainer()
        }
        return containerImpl!
    }
    
    var privatePersistentStore: NSPersistentStore?
    
    private func makeLazyContainer() -> NSPersistentContainer {
        var container: NSPersistentContainer? = nil
        
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179862/cloudkit-sync-using-nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-in-ios13

        let dontSyncToiCloud = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "dontSyncToiCloud")
        var cloudContainer : NSPersistentCloudKitContainer? = nil
        if !dontSyncToiCloud {
            print("syncing to iCloud")
            cloudContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Model")
            container = cloudContainer
        } else {
            print("not syncing to iCloud")
            container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        }
        
        let description = container!.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
        description!.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description!.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        
        container!.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {
            (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } else {
                self.privatePersistentStore = container!.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStore(for: storeDescription.url!)
            }
        })
        
        container!.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container!.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

        if !dontSyncToiCloud {
            // Only initialize the schema when building the app with the Debug build configuration.
#if DEBUG
            do {
                // Use the container to initialize the development schema.
                // thise needs to be done after persistent store load
                print("initialize the development schema")
                try cloudContainer!.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: [])
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
#endif
        }
        
        do {
            try container!.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
        } catch {
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to pin viewContext to the current generation:\(error)")
        }
        
        return container!
    }
}
```